# A facility, in a rural setting, used to breed and train horses?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

In English, there seems to be a specific term for all things equestrian. How is a horse breeding and training facility in a rural setting called?

In portuguese, it is caled a "Haras" (the term is current and very often used). The google translator gives me "horse farm" or "stud farm".

The word Haras exists in english (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/haras) but seems to be falling out of use, as [this ngram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Haras&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CHaras%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BHaras%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bharas%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHARAS%3B%2Cc0).

Is there any more current idiom for this facility, or "horse/stud farm" is as glamorous as we get?

Comment: Have you tried "ranch"? A large farm, especially in North America or Australia, where cattle or other animals are bred [OOD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ranch)

Comment: @Rathony I am looking for something to convey the meaning that it is a horse-exclusive facility.

Comment: I posted my answer with "horse ranch".

Comment: If I'm dressed appropriately for the ranch am I wearing... ranch dressing?

Comment: @DigitalChris must.. not.. feed.... trolls. I think you are wearing a ranch dress. If you dress inside a ranch, you are ranch dressing. But if you are wearing ranch dressing, please avoid truck stops.

Answer (score 10):

Google Translator is right about both "stud farm" and "horse farm". These are indeed the correct terms:

> A **stud farm** or **stud** in animal husbandry is an establishment for selective breeding of livestock.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stud_farm

**Stud** is defined in this way:

> a. A group of animals, **especially horses**, kept for breeding.
>
> b. A male animal, such as a stallion, that is kept for breeding.
>
> c. **A stable or farm where these animals are kept.**

([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stud))

You are correct about "haras", too. It's a bit more specific, but also archaic:

> **haras:** archaic : a horse-breeding establishment : **stud farm**

(Webster's Unabridged)

["Horse farm"](http://www.crerunfarm.com/pages/aboutcrerun.html) seems to be the most widely used term **in the US**, according to [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horse%20farm%2Chorse%20ranch%2Cstud%20farm&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chorse%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhorse%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHorse%20Farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHorse%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHORSE%20FARM%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chorse%20ranch%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhorse%20ranch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHorse%20Ranch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHORSE%20RANCH%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHorse%20ranch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cstud%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bstud%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStud%20Farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSTUD%20FARM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStud%20farm%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

[In British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=horse%20farm%2Chorse%20ranch%2Cstud%20farm&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Chorse%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhorse%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHorse%20Farm%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chorse%20ranch%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhorse%20ranch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHorse%20Ranch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cstud%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bstud%20farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStud%20Farm%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSTUD%20FARM%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BStud%20farm%3B%2Cc0), however, **"stud farm"** appears to be the most popular term:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think the term you are looking for is ***[stables](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stable) with a riding-ground*:**

> - a building in which horses are kept, fed, and cared for (M-W)

Note:

***[Riding stable](http://noun%20a%20place%20where%20horses%20are%20kept%20for%20people%20to%20ride):***

> - a place where horses are kept for people to ride.

***Training stable:***

> - a place for training horses,  like starting young horses and re-educating grown ones.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Josh, but I am looking for a term of a broader facility (that would include stables, barn, riding track, obstacle course, etc etc.

Comment: @Mindwin But a large stables would include those kinds of things - Shula in *the Archers* (BBC Radio soap) was expecting to install a wet facility, a training pool for her horses, but that got ruled out when she didn't get the expected family legacy.

Comment: @WS2 tum tee tum tee tum tee taaa

Answer (score 6):

"[***Ranch***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ranch)" is broadly used as it means:

> A large farm, especially in North America or Australia, where cattle
>   or other animals are bred

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

If you google "***horse ranch***", you get 654,000 hits, which means it is *more* braodly used than "***stud farm***" with 524,000 hits.

Comment: This may be the case, but no such facility exists with that name in the UK, at least. The small town of Newmarket alone has dozens of stud farms, but not a single horse ranch.

Comment: @JHCL I thank everyone for showing all those regional nuances.

Comment: Rathony, do not bash. @JHCL is adding important info. He is not decreasing the merit of your answer, just enhancing it. and BTW, "horse farm" has 4,610,000 hits on google.

Comment: And I am really liking the Horse Ranch term. But I am not a native english speaker. More reason that comments from natives like @JHCL are important here.

Comment: @Mindwin You didn't ask for a word to be used specifically in UK. I really don't understand why he would comment like that? Just because any word is not used in UK doesn't necessarily mean it is not popular. I found some usages, but I would not argue about it.

Comment: (disclaimer: internet is bad at conveying emotions) - Rathony, your reaction "what's your point" to @JHCL comment sounded too defensive. He is enriching the discussion around your answer. Your comment above, sounds defensive too. Relax. We are all building the awesome together here.

Comment: @Mindwin The only reason I didn't mention "horse/stud farm" is that you already mentioned it in your question. That's all. The meaning of the word "stud" is changing and that's why the usage of "stud farm" might be declining. I am not sure. I just suggested a better alternative and that's all.

Comment: good, good. now lets quit it here, before a mod bashes us for extended discussions.

Answer (score 3):

If the haras is a pretty large one, consider calling it a horse [breeding] [**spread**](http://www.daleperkinshorseshow.com/Horses.htm)

> ***spread***
>
> : (*AmEng & CanEng*) a large farm or ranch
>   [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/spread)
>
> : a ranch or homestead especially in the western United States
>   [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spread)

Comment: I'm American, and I have heard the terms *horse farm* and a *horse ranch* but never *horse spread*.

Comment: @GEdgar regional feedback! maybe it is a canadian thing?

Comment: Elian, horse spread is more commonly used for racing and is less usually associated with a horse-exclusive facility.

Comment: @Mindwin Check this out, Mindwin https://books.google.fr/books?id=RawIiKPfrWEC&pg=PT53&dq=%22Tabor+Evans%22+%22horse+breeding+spread%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwAGoVChMI-f_Ii935yAIVC34aCh32vwz_#v=onepage&q=%22Tabor%20Evans%22%20%22horse%20breeding%20spread%22&f=false. Merriam-Webster states "spread" as especially Western US  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spread

Comment: @GEdgar - In the TV show Bonanza, the Cartwrights had a ranch known as Pondurosa. It was a six hundred thousand acre *spread*. It's not a *horse spread*, the whole thing is a *spread*; a homestead.

Answer (score 1):

"Ranch" implies, if not denotes, work. If you are seeking a trained draft animal or a horse to herd cattle with, a ranch is the place you go. Horses are not intrinsically part of the definition, but are traditionally present. Thus, you would, if you were looking to get such a horse, specify "horse ranch".

If, on the other hand, you want a horse to race or tool about on, you hit up a trainer's stable. There are, as noted elsewhither herein, multiple sub-types of stables, but you don't need to specify further if those distinctions are not of interest. Similarly, it's accepted as a term for the entire complex and not just specifically the housing.

Re the dialects (Many USA) that I'm familiar with: 
Neither "horse ranch" nor "stable" will seem quaint if used as described. "Stud farm" would only seem off if used for more than a breeding ground. "Horse farm" would be clearly understood, but *would* sound a bit childish, and would not be taken to imply anything other than a breeding facility.